# Sorting array of arrays of objects by value

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is an array of arrays:
`var people = [[{name: "John", age: "15"}], [{name: "Maria", age: "26"}], [{name: "Alex", age: "9"}]]`
How can I move "John" to the end of **people** by his *age* value? I'm honestly beginner in JS and looking for any help with this task

Answer (score 0):

```js
var people = [[{name: "John", age: 15}], [{name: "Maria", age: 26}], [{name: "Alex", age: 9}]];

people.sort((a,b) => a[0].age - b[0].age);

console.log(people);
```

Observations:

- John would not be at the end if sorted by age -- his age is in the middle
- You should use integers for your ages. If you don't wrap your sort function values in `parseInt`.
- The array-of-one-element-arrays thing doesn't seem to make sense -- you may want to rethink that structure.